# Why can't I run debug version of .NET program in the machine didn't install visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, release, visual-studio-debugging

I have a debug version of a .NET 4.0 application, I install the .NET 4.0 Framework in in this machine, however, I didn't install Microsoft Visual Studio.

Why I can only run Release version of application, but can't run the debug version of application?

I guess dlls in the debug version of application may refer to some dll of Visual Studio? Does anyone know exactly why?

Comment: You should be able to run an assembly compiled in debug mode. What, exactly, happens when you try to run it?

Comment: @DBM It throw an FileNotFoundException.Message like below:        Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or ass
embly 'xxxx.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specifie
d module could not be found.

Comment: Did you install the full framework or the client profile? Try the full framework if you only installed client profile. Also, is that your DLL or a framework DLL being referenced in the error?

Comment: Does it depend on unmanaged project or DLL?

Comment: @Tetsujin no Oni I already install full framework include both Client Profile and Extended

Comment: @imJustice What's "xxxx.dll"? Is it one of *your* assemblies?

Comment: We need the name of "xxxx.dll" to try tofind out what it belongs t - because this is the culprit. Only. You miss an installed piece. VS comes witha  lot of stuff, you must have missed a condition for your software.

Answer (score 0):

<s>A debug build is specifically for debugging your program. It includes some extra protections and hooks to allow you to step through and test your program. These require special debug runtimes that generally come with Visual Studio.</s>

A release build strips all of this extra functionality, so all you need to run it is the .NET framework.

EDIT: After some more research, it does look like the debug builds should be roughly equivalent to the release builds. The main difference seems to be that the debug build creates a pdb file with the extra lookup info for the debugger, and may be a little less aggressive with optimizations.

Comment: That might have been true about Win32/C/C++, but not so on .NET.

Comment: Conditional statements may be stripped out at compile time, but you can run a .NET assembly anywhere that the framework is present.